# Слово "язычник"

Tags: этимология

Откуда произошло слово "язычник" и родственно ли оно слову "язык"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слово **язык** в древности употреблялось также в знач. «народ», «много». 
У Пушкина, например, находим: "*Слух обо мне пройдет по всей Руси великой, //  И назовет меня всяк сущий в ней **язык**,// И гордый внук славян, и финн, и ныне дикой //       Тунгуз, и друг степей калмык.*"

Отсюда заимствованное из ст.-сл. яз. слово **язычник** «поклоняющийся многим богам (идолам)», «идолопоклонник», которое является калькой греч. ethnikos «языческий», от ethnos «народ» (много); от него в рус. яз. термин *этнография* «наука, изучающая материальную и духовную культуру народов».

Comment: откуда видно, что язык было в значении много?

Answer (score 7):

По теме. Да, язык = народ, племя. Но к "много" не имеет никакого отношения. Соответственно и язычество совсем не "многобожие". Всё гораздо проще. Язычник, языческий - относящийся к чужим племенам. Этим термином обозначили переводчики Библии еврейские термины "Гой" (нееврей) и подобные. Понятие же "язычество" возникло много позже и означало религию соседних нехристианских народов (=язЫков). Тот факт, что они были в основном политеистическими (в широком смысле, т.е. неавраамическими) никак не связан с этимологией самого слова "язычество".

Answer (score -1):

Слово "ἐθνικός" в древнегреческом [означало, в частности, "язычник"](https://biblehub.com/greek/1482.htm). Фасмер считает, [что "язычник" - калька с него](http://www.endic.ru/fasmer/Jazchnik-17035.html).

Думаю, желание употребления "язычник" в смысле "идолопоклонник" натолкнулось бы на противодействие того, что по структуре оно должно означать что-то связанное с языком либо с народом.

Предлагаю альтернативную этимологию, или дополнительное влияние на установление этого слова в этом смысле.

"Язык" в тюркских языках означает "грех". В частности, [в современном татарском](https://syzlek.ru/?word=%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA), но употребляется редко, а часто употребляется слово "гөнаһ".

Слово "язык" в татарском, на мой взгляд, легко этимологизируется как [яз](https://syzlek.ru/?word=%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%83)+ык что означает "написанное", а смысл этого в том, что согласно Исламу, все грехи, но также и хорошие деяния, записываются ангелами, которые находятся с левой и с правой стороны каждого человека, а также все события изначально записаны в некой сокровенной книге у Бога. Также, кроме "писать", у глагола "яз" есть смысл "предопределять", цитата из статьи, на которую я сослался в этом абзаце:

> 10. рел. обычно со словами ходай, алла и др. предназначено, предопределено богом, судьбой; үзеңә язган мал кайта ул ( погов. )
>       богатство (добро), которое тебе суждено, вернётся; алла (ходай) язган
>       бог дал; предопределено богом; алла язган булса, эшләрбез бог даст,
>       сделаем

А также есть второй способ этимологизации: яз+ык, (что из другого "[яз](http://tatpoisk.net/dict/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)"), означает "нечто, что осталось в результате схода с пути, неудавания придержаться".

Также я обнаружил, что в старославянском слово "язычник" в значении "язычник" употреблялось редко: [Какая была частота употребления слова "язычник" в старославянском?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448124/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc) . Для понятия "язычники" было слово "языцы".

Древнетюркский словарь стр. 251:
[image: Древнетюркский словарь jazuq][image: Древнетюркский словарь глагол jaz3]

Этимологический словарь Ахметьянова:
[image: словарь ахметьянова, язык][image: словарь ахметьянова, глагол яз3]

Comment: А почему вы считаете возможным заимствование тюркского слова в русский без фонетических изменений?

Comment: @Aer некоторые фонемы изменяются, но в случае с фонемами этого слова, думаю, изменений наверно не было. и вообще, некоторые изменения есть. если посмотреть на древнетюркский словарь, то там приведена форма "язук". если заимствование шло из этого варианта, у изменилась на ы. кроме того, конечный звук къ изменился на к/ч. и в случае со звуком ы, он в татарском немного отличается от русского звука ы. также звук а в первом слоге в татарском отличается от русского звука а.

Comment: Насколько я понял, содержательной частью вашего потока информации можно ситать утверждение о проникновении слова "язык" из тюркских - на основании некоторых фонетических совпадений. И только. Убедительности никакой. Да, может там в татарских чего и проискодит, но причем тут русский язык?! Дайте хоть одно внтное пояснение относительно русского языка, сошлитесь на лингвистов-русистов или хоть что-нибудь... А то прям чудивщина какая прёт. Или Рыбаков - только наоборот.

Comment: @behemothus "на основании некоторых фонетических совпадений. И только." - нет, а фонетических и семантических.

Comment: Семантических не вижу. До даже если они есть, этого мало. Начнем с того, сто слово "язык" общеславянское и очень древнее. Каким боком тут вообще тюрки, если интенсивное тюркское влияние в язык началось ну никак не ранее X-XI веков ?!

Comment: @behemothus семантическое совпадение состоит в том, что язычников можно было бы называть грешниками.

Comment: @behemothus болгары-славяне частично возникли из болгар-тюрков. википедия, статья "славяне": 681 год — образование булгарами, славянскими и фракийсками племенами, под предводительством хана Аспаруха, Первого Болгарского царства. ... Между VI и X веками большая часть славян приняла христианство: восточные и юго-восточные по Византийскому обряду, а Западные и Юго-Западные по Римскому обряду.

Comment: Я знаю эту историю, но тюркизмы того периода единичны, строго ограничены собственно болгаорским и не вошли в общеславянский лексикон. А слово "язык", извините, он язык во всех славянских. Вы приводите много сведений, которые никакой доказательной базой в этимологическое сфере не обладают.

Comment: *семантическое совпадение состоит в том, что язычников можно было бы называть грешниками* - ну мало ли, кого как можно назвать. Фантазии ваши.

Comment: @behemothus мало, в языке бывают десятки тысяч слов, и большая часть из них не подошли бы по смыслу. например, нет смысла называть язычников столами, стульями, деревьями.

Comment: @behemothus я не про слово "язык" написал, а про "язычник" и "языческое", и сказал что возможно это только повлияло, наряду с влиянием греческого... т. е. могло быть сразу 2 пути происхождения слова... не все люди знали греческий, не все знали тюркский, но те которые знали, видели в выборе именно этого слова смысл... и в старославянском этих слов могло и не быть, они могли быть более поздними словами, см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/448124 .