# Язычник от слова язык

Tags: значение-слов

В школьной программе к язычникам относят, как правило, кровожадные племена. Когда я просил учителя объяснить, его ответ провоцировал дополнительные вопросы и ни один ответ не устраивал. Я склоняюсь к своей версии как более логичной. Язычники — это как раз люди образованные и владеющие многими языками, в современном определении полиглоты. Видимо, из зависти их очернили. Кто и что думает?

Comment: Википедия же есть: ["Язычество"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Язычество). Нет, к полиглотам это не имеет никакого отношения, но и не все язычники были "кровожадными племенами", конечно. :)

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы делаете слишком много пунктуационных ошибок.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Слово "язычник"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba)

Comment: Я думаю, что вам следовало хотя бы посмотреть, что УЖЕ думали на эту тему. Хотя если вас даже версия учителя не устраивала настолько, что вы "забыли" её изложить...

Answer (score 2):

Язычник действительно от слова "язык", только в другом значении. Среди многих значений слова у Даля есть следующие:

> Народ, земля, с одноплеменным населеньем своим, с одинаковою речью.
> Язык самарийский, Деян. самаритяне. Рцыте во языцех (всем народам),
> яко Господь воцарися, Псалтирь. Поганыи же половци свокупиша весь язык
> свой на рускую землю, летопись. Нашествие дванадесяти языков на Русь,
> 1812 год.

> | Язык, церк. чужой народ, иноверцы, иноплеменники; |
> язычники, идолопоклонники. Убо и языкам Бог покаяние даде в живот, Деян. Всяк язык Бога хвалит.

http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=44231

Т.е. язык – это народ. А язычник – это иноверец, инородец с церковной точки зрения.

Что нам говорит «Старославянский словарь» Москва, издание 1894 года ?

> 3. Народ, племя ... Например, "встанет языкъ на языкъ"; "да един ч(лове)къ оумьретъ за люди, а не вьсь языкъ погыбнетъ"; "въскую
>    шяташя  ся езыци"; "яко пр(оро)ка бо въ языцехъ положихъ тя" и т.д.
> 4. «Чужестранцы, иноплеменники, чужеземцы, представители чужого народа,с чуждыми верованиями,традициями и культурой»

Это не наша современная трактовка, и не советская. Это еще императорская Россия. Итак, ЯЗЫЧНИК - это  представитель чужого народа. Поэтому раньше у нас никогда и  не говорили, что
славяне были язычниками. А по отношению к кому
они были язычниками? По отношению к другим народам, говорящим на иных  языках, почитающим других Богов, с совершенно другими традициями, бытом и культурой - вот для них славяне были язычниками.

Итак, термин язычество происходит из Нового завета, в котором под язычеством подразумевались народы или «языки», противополагаемые ранним христианским общинам.  https://wiki2.org/ru/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE

Значит, все дохристианские народы, племена - язычники.

Среди древних язычников преобладало мифологическое мировоззрение. В древности человек не отделял себя от природы и одновременно обожествлял её, придавая элементам окружающего мира человеческие черты. У греков обожествлялись человеческие страсти, у славян — природные явления, у индейцев — духи предков. В суровом и недружелюбном мире человек искал себе союзников и покровителей, которые по характеру походили бы на людей и могли бы помочь им.

В древние времена язычество было синонимом жестокости. Человеческие жертвоприношения в те времена не были чем-то необычным. Во время засухи или неурожая, чтобы умилостивить богов, в жертву приносили детей. После удачного похода — пленных. Во время ежегодных праздников — сильных воинов. При погребении вождей — их жён и наложниц. Это и  жертвоприношения индейцев майя в Доколумбовой Америке, и кровавые ритуалы ацтеков. В истории любого народа можно найти подобные кровавые пятна. Потом человеческие жертвы заменили животными.

Comment: *Значит, все дохристианские народы, племена - язычники.* — вряд ли кто-то назовёт сейчас дохристианских последователей буддизма в Древней Индии язычниками. В целом мне ответ понятен, и я его поддержал. Но я сомневаюсь, что критически настроенный школьник поймёт его так же. Поясню на примере. *В древние времена язычество было синонимом жестокости.* — эту мысль я бы формулировал совсем по-другому, поскольку в древние времена ещё не было понятия "язычество", и даже "жестокость" понималась тогда иначе (но я Вашу мысль понял, конечно).

Comment: @grizzly насчет буддистов - вопрос сложный и глубоко философский. Если кратко: могут быть разные подходы. Но ваш комментарий заставил меня набросать свой ответ. Хотя это трудно сделать, не влезая  слишком глубоко в философию.

Comment: @behemothus Основная идея моего комментария — мы отвечаем школьнику и хорошо бы отвечать на соответствующем уровне, согласовывая значения терминов со школьной программой. В крайнем случае подчёркивать, что это не для школы, если очень охота зарыться глубоко в философию (хотя я против этого в данном случае).

Comment: @grizzly  Ааа... Ну извините. Я-то думал, вопрос принципиальный. ))) (+) Хотя это еще тоже надо уточнить, нужно ли (с точки зрения формата ресурса ориентироваться) на уровень задавшего вопрос. SE вроде как позиционирует себя базой знаний, а не сервисом вопросов-ответов. То есть этакой энциклопедией, а не справочным бюро... )))

Comment: @behemothus Я всегда понимал SE как сервис вопросов-ответов, но не в этом дело (это можно будет обсудить на мете). В любом случае будет не лишним сказать (хотя бы в комментариях), что значение термина изменилось со временем и может по-разному восприниматься в разных традициях. Собственно, я для этого комментировал, а не ради критики. И мне всегда нравится в ответах Людмилы, когда она говорит, что в школьной программе принято так-то, а в вузах и в академической среде может быть по-разному у разных авторов (мне самому такое разъяснение обычно полезно и интересно).

Answer (score 1):

*Ну, поскольку вопрос не спешат признавать дубликатом перенесу сюда ответ с небольшими необходимыми дополнениями.*

Язычник и язычество появились в языке немного по-разному, хотя восходят, понятно, к слову "язык".  Язык здесь "народ", "племя". К "языку" как средству общения (т. е. в значении речь, говор, диалект) и тем более к понятию "много" не имеет прямого отношения. Соответственно, и **язычество** совсем не "многобожие". Всё гораздо проще.

Язычник, языческий - относящийся к чужим племенам. Этим термином обозначили переводчики Библии еврейские термины "гой" (нееврей) и подобные. Понятие же "язычество" возникло много позже и означало религию соседних нехристианских народов (=язЫков). Тот факт, что они были в основном политеистическими (в широком смысле, т.е. неавраамическими) никак не связан с этимологией самого слова "язычество".

(+) И по поводу буддистов и прочих.

Важно, что язычниками не назвали ни евреев (иудаистов), ни мусульман, хотя это не христианские конфессии. Христиане в общем-то понимали, что у всех трех авраамических религий один и тот же Бог, поэтому к язычникам отнести их приверженцев нельзя. А вот насчет буддистов и прочих представителей крупных религий вопрос спорный. Просто вопрос так не стоял, о буддистах, зороастрийцах, езидах и прочих представителях неаавраамических религий  было известно слишком мало, чтобы как-то выделять их в отдельную классификационную группу по отношению к язычеству.

Философия (в том числе подзабытая ныне марксистская доктрина исторического материализма) решает эти вопросы несколько по-иному, разделяя верования и собственно религию. Так вот не будет большой ошибкой считать язычниками всех исповедующих верования